# Unable to create mat-radio-group from FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms, formgroups

I am trying to create a set of radio buttons from a static set of FormControls within a FormGroup, and default checked when one is true.

Component.ts:

```
export class RadioOverviewExample {

  public formModel: FormGroup;

  constructor() {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.formModel = new FormGroup({
      formName: new FormControl(''),
      formId: new FormControl(''),
      radioOptions: new FormGroup({
        train: new FormControl(true),
        subway: new FormControl(false),
        bus: new FormControl(false),
        taxi: new FormControl(false)
      })
    })
  }    
}
```

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="formModel">

    <mat-radio-group formGroupName="radioOptions">
        <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let op of radioOptions.controls">
      {{op}}
    </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>

</form>
```

Error:

```
Error: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined
```

Expected Output:

```
[X] Train   [] Subway   [] Bus   [] Taxi
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kc5k9c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mat-radio-group only allow choose an unique option among differents options, so you only need an unique FormControl. You use an auxiliar array to show the options -not a control in Form

```
transports=[{value:0,text:"Train"},
       {value:1,text:Subway},
       {value:2,text:"Bus"},
       {value:3,text="Taxi"}
      ]

<mat-radio-group formGroupName="radioOptions">
    <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let op of transports" [value]="op.value">
    {{op.text}}
   </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

and your formModel.get('radioOptions').value becomes 0,1,2 or 3

You can also use a mat-radio-group stand alone and use [value] and (change) to give value to the differents controls of formGroup. Remember, a FormControl exist even if we has no input control

```
<mat-radio-group [value]="getIndex()"
                 (change)=setValue($event.value) 
    <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let op of transports" [value]="op.value">
    {{op.text}}
   </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

And in .ts

```
  getIndex() //return the index of the first is true
  {
    return Object.keys(this.formModel.value.radioOptions).findIndex(
      x => this.formModel.value.radioOptions[x]
    );
  }
  setValue(index: number) {
    Object.keys((this.formModel.get("radioOptions") as FormGroup).controls).forEach(
      (field, i) => {
        const control=this.formModel.get("radioOptions."+field)
        if (control)
          control.setValue(i == index);
      }
    );
  }
```

[stackblitz with the last part](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n4l6qc?file=src/app/radio-overview-example.ts)

Comment: Thanks for this, and the explanation, helped understanding alot. Just wanted to check, within getIndex(), looks like const field is redundant?

Comment: sorry, I left it in the code by error, I just remove it